# How does node-csgo package access player's profile details like competitive rank?

Tags: node.js, npm, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I am trying out [csgo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csgo) package for getting csgo profile details using node.js. I was wondering how is it able to access my csgo profile after logging in as the public api for csgo doesn't provide competitive rank and other stats provided by this package.

Thankyou in advance for answering.

Answer (score 1):

The [code](https://github.com/joshuaferrara/node-csgo/blob/master/handlers/player.js#L22) sends a protobuf request for a `k_EMsgGCCStrike15_v2_ClientRequestPlayersProfile` and decodes a [`CMsgGCCStrike15_v2_MatchmakingGC2ClientHello`](https://github.com/SteamDatabase/Protobufs/blob/fb5970a1a9638fc464c8d12d11d8586d28e02fdd/csgo/cstrike15_gcmessages.proto#L557-L577)

These read like they are requests the game sends back and forth rather than the public API. Maybe the underlying modules use internal Protobuf definitions that have been extracted.

Comment: Oh so basically these are the like http calls done from within the game ? Like when I click some button etc ?

Comment: Any idea on how to track these requests sent by the game? I have heard that we can track the network traffic flowing from our pc. But will be able to detect the calls made by the game? If yes then any suggestion on which tool to use for that purpose ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this so can't say for sure, just had a quick look and that's what it seems like to me. I can't see anything this game specific in the [steamworks API](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk) if that's the api you were referring to earlier.

Comment: re network tools - wireshark, telerik fiddler, you will often need to know how to "man in the middle" TLS traffic for wireshark to be useful as well